# In code-golf is it always ok to print ASCII digits when an integer is asked for?

Tags: discussion, rules

When the question clearly asks for an integer is it always OK to just print the ASCII digits of the integer without actually generating the integer value?

The consensus is yes.  It's the programs/functions output that matters not the intermediate (integer value).

Comment: @mbomb007 Which answer there adresses this?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of an answer, but a duplicate of the question. He can create an answer, then we can vote on it. It should be noted that the only time it's possible to differentiate between a string and an integer is with return values of functions. When outputting to STDOUT, or a file, there is no difference.

Comment: Probably this one
Programs may output by displaying it on screen.
and this one
Functions may output via the same methods as full programs